# Testing for 100,000 concurrent users on a single machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

My code is in ASP.NET MVC Razor C# and Database is SQL Server 2012. Right now the code is on localhost.

ok. Before moving to the server, I want to test the website design should able to scale/support 100,000 concurrent users.

Question : I am a .NET Developer only. Is there any way to do the testing for 100,000 concurrent users on a single machine ?

Comment: Suggest stress testing to see where one web machine/sql server is at. Scaling is part of design/architecture more-so than code. There are too many factors involved to answer the question but I would guess your goal of 100,000 is unlikely. Also, unit testing and concurrent testing are something I consider incompatible. Do them separately.

Comment: @Atoms: Sir, I apologize for the wrong Title, It was to be Testing for the concurrent user.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, you can create load tests in visual studio (using VS Ultimate/Enterprise test tools) no problems.

Some basic info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293540(v=vs.110).aspx

**But...**

Your machine will not be able to handle creating 100,000 simultaneous requests, let alone the site/application servicing those requests on a single machine.

You really need to setup a staging environment that will mimic your production implementation, then deploy and load test on that with load balancing and all the bells and whistles. Otherwise the load/stress test will be a waste of time, the stats you will get back from the test will show 100% timeouts over ~1,000 concurrent users (which is not at all a representation of the speed of your app, just the speed of your machine).

Then once you have said staging environment setup. I would suggest spreading the load test over 5-10 PC/VM's as well. This will give the best "real-world" results.

Comment: Sir, Thanks a lot. I am check the link above.

Answer (score -1):

As per your question, you cannot test an application (either web or desktop application) with 100,000 users without the help of testing software's. The type of testing you are willing to perform is known as volume testing or stress testing in which number of users access the application at the same time and we observe the behavior of the application. This can be done by using a software called HP-Performance Center developed by HP. But it is a licensed software. You wont get it for free.